# Value maximization formula for startups

Tags: calculus, optimization

here's a math question.

It's about startups "philosophy" of maximizing value for customers as oppose to their own value. I'd like to represent this in mathematical form.

The variables:

x: perceived value provided by your solution to the customer
y: perceived value provided by competitive solution to the customer

a: value captured by you
b: value captured by your customer

the goal is to maximize

x-y, and
b under constraint of minimum value captured by you

(x-y) <-- this is the value advantage

of which I want to maximize b; in other words x-y is shared between a and b so a and b are somehow proportional to it.

So, the question is: how to put this in a formula?

Thanks.

Comment: Put what in a formula, and why? Words do just as good, as shown.

Comment: Thanks for the praise :) Due to elegance: I'd like to express it in the simplest possible form. That's the beauty of maths, right?